# Model::insert() is not updating timestamps

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, timestamp

I added the timestamps in the Migration(Schema) and the model

```
$table->timestamps();  //In the Schema

public $timestamps = true; //In the model
```

I made an array with all fields of the database and inserted into the database.

```
Checkin::insert($input);
```

In the table, it updates all the fields except the updated_at, created_at timestamps

I have another(default) model for Users and it updates the timestamps. In that model, I am using the ->save() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `insert`, you should use `create` if you want the timestamps to be set:

```
Checkin::create($input);
```

You can also do

```
$checking = Checkin::create($input);
```

which will give you the just created checkin.

Make sure the fields are fillable by adding this to your model:

```
protected $fillable = array(
    'name',
    'field_1',
    'field_2',
    ... // all the fields you want to be mass-assignable here
    );
```

Also, there's no need to set `public $timestamps = true;` as that is the default in Laravel if you're using Eloquent models.

Comment: I tried it.. I believe but its is throwing a mass assignment error

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer with how you can set the fillable fields of your model to make them mass-assignable.

Comment: So I have to do that to all my tables, Are there any other advantages of create() over insert() other than this?

Comment: That's indeed strongly recommended. Using create() also means you can use events like `creating` or `created` in your application to hook into and add some logic, which can be very useful.

Comment: `create()` is a Eloquent Model method, `insert()` is inherited from a query builder, thus it does not do anything beside a insert query to the database.